# Get response from HttpResponseMessage in unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit, httpresponse, .net-framework-version

I've got this method in my controller, it queries data from database in this case it takes job with an id that's provided and sends HttpResponse message to the website containing some attachment(pdf, txt, etc):

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("jobs/{id}/attachment")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAttachment([FromUri]Guid id)
    {
        if (job.Blob == null)
        {
            // The job exists, but has no result data
            return this.CreateApiError(ApiError.ApiErrors.NO_CONTENT, "Job has no attachment", HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        var result = new HttpResponseMessage();
        result.Content = new StreamContent(new System.IO.MemoryStream(job.Blob));
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = job.Filename;
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

        return result;
    }
```

It returns `status 200` and works fine.

I'm writing unit test for it that looks like this:
I mock a job data, add it to database with `JobQuery.Update(job);`
and then try to get it's data:

```
[Test]
    public void GetAttachmentTest()
    {
        var text = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{\"name\":\"John\"}");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\" + "Report -12.txt", text);
        var job = new Job
        {
            Id = Guid.Parse("deadbeef-dead-beef-0000-000000000000"),
            Filename = "Report -12.txt",
            AudienceOrganizationId = organization.Id,
            AudienceUserId = apiUser.Id,
            Blob = text
    };

        HttpResponseMessage getAttachment;
        try
        {
            getAttachment = this.Get<HttpResponseMessage>(this.url + this.prefix + "jobs/" + job.id + "/attachment");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Get jobs/{id}/attachment failed");
            return;
        }
    }
```

`this.Get<HttpResponseMessage>(this.url + this.prefix + "jobs/" + job.id + "/attachment");` goes to controller and looks for job with that id and takes attachment to return.
In controller it works fine, if I look at the response from website I get it as well, but I can't make it to get it here in my unit test.
And here on `getAttachment` I get null. How should I change my unit test to get response?
The job is saved in database. It has an attachment file which I get with HttpResponse.

Comment: Confirm if this is asp.net-web-api-2.* or asp.net-core.

Comment: where does `job` come from in `GetAttachment`?

Comment: `HttpResponseMessage` is no longer used as a controller response type in core

Comment: Probably, but I'm only writing tests there, not really supposed to change code in controller. So I am just looking for workaround

Comment: finding a workaround for things that are no longer supported by a framework makes no sense.

Comment: What is `Get<>` doing? Also you are passing a different id that the deadbeef one in the url.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: This question lacks a [mcve], which makes it difficult for assistance to be provided.

Comment: Added more information